# How to rename branch to remove capitalization?

Tags: git, github, git-branch

I named a branch `Name` instead of `name` and would like to change it to the latter.

I tried renaming the branch locally:

```
git branch -m tmp
```

Deleting the branch on github:

```
git push origin --delete Name
```

Renaming the temp branch:

```
git branch -m name
```

Pushing the branch to github:

```
 git push origin name
```

But when I push the branch to github, I get this output:

```
Total 0 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
To https://github.com/xx/xx.git
 * [new branch]      name -> Name
```

Why did github rename the branch when I pushed it? How can I rename my branch from `Name` to `name`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `git push origin old_name:new_name` to define how the branch will be called on the server. You probably have the remote branch name in your .git/config file which was not updated.

Answer (score 0):

First, from the branch you want to rename you do the following:

```
git branch -m name
```

Then we need to delete the old name branch from the remote and push the new branch name from the local to the remote branch.

```
git push origin :Name name
```

Last you need to switch to the branch and then:

```
git push origin -u name
```

Referance:
https://multiplestates.wordpress.com/2015/02/05/rename-a-local-and-remote-branch-in-git/