# Issue while renaming a branch from uppercase to lowercase on local and remote git repos

Tags: git-branch, git

As I am new to git I didn't know that it is a good practice to have the branch names lowercase so I ended up having it uppercase. So now I am trying to rename the branch and tried what has been suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25704330/how-to-rename-branch-to-remove-capitalization) but no luck.

Commands that I also tried

```
git branch -m newfeature
git branch -m NEWFEATURE newfeature
```

The error I get when I try the above commands is

```
fatal: A branch named 'newfeature' already exists
```

Comment: What is the output of the first command when you run it?

Comment: @mnestorov it is the same error for both the commands.

Comment: If you run `git branch -a` and look at your branch names, then do you have such a branch that already exists?

Comment: @mnestorov yes it does exist but with uppercase

Comment: can you try it with the `-M` option, because you might be on windows. Since Windows is case-sensitive about such things, you need to force the move.

Answer (score 6):

Two points:

- If your Git repository is located on a case-insensitive filesystem (say, NTFS with default settings on Windows or HFS[+] on MacOS), any attempt to rename a branch to a case-different version of itself will fail.

  The reason is that ("fresh") branches in Git are stored as plain files with the names of such files being the name of the branch they represent.
  On a case-insensitive filesystem, names "foo", "FOO" and "FoO" are considered to refer to the same file, so it's impossible to create a file named "whatever" if a file named "WHATEVER" already exists in the same directory.
- To force owerwriting a branch when using the `git branch -m` command, you may use its upper-cased version: `git branch -M` would replace the target branch even if it exists.

To recap, the simplest way to rename a branch is to trip it through some neutral name which is currently not taken:

```
git branch -m temp newfeature
git branch -m newfeature NEWFEATURE
```

---

Also note that if you only care about the name of the branch you have pushed,
you may well rename it remotely: the command

```
git push origin WHATEVER:refs/heads/whatever :refs/heads/WHATEVER
```

would push the local branch "WHATEVER" to create a branch named "whatever" in the remote repo known as "origin" and then delete the branch named "WHATEVER" there.

Provided "WHATEVER" locally contains the same history as was already pushed to "origin" under that same name, the command would not even transfer any data.

Answer (score 0):

The reason git is telling you that `newfeature` already exists, is because with the first command, you have already renamed you branch to `newfeature`. The `git branch -m newfeature` command will move **your current branch** to the `newfeature` branch name.

So both commands are correct, you just did it on the first go.

**NOTE:** if you are on Windows, which has a case-sensitive filesystem, you need to pass the `-M` option. It stands for `--move --force` to force the rename.

You can view all your branches with

```
git branch -a
```

and see what their names are.

Comment: I tried the second command when the first one gave me the same error. And the second command gave the same error.

Comment: @Shrugo please see the edit, as it might be relevant to your case.